# iOS sqlite3_step hold / freeze after last row data

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sqlite

My sqlite3_step holds for a 1s after read of last row data. Why?

```
-(NSDictionary*)specificationItemsForConfigurationsIds:(NSString*)configurationsIdsStr
{
    [self databaseOpen];

    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT SpecItem.id,SpecItem.name,ConfigurationSpec.configuration_id\
                   FROM (SpecItem INNER JOIN ConfigurationSpec ON ConfigurationSpec.spec_item_id=SpecItem.id)\
                   WHERE (SpecItem.parent_id=12 OR SpecItem.parent_id=34 OR SpecItem.id=23 OR SpecItem.id=27) AND ConfigurationSpec.configuration_id IN (%@)",configurationsIdsStr];

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

NSMutableDictionary* configurationsWithSpecItems = [NSMutableDictionary new];

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        int specItemId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        NSString* specItemName = [self sqlite3_column_text_asString_ofStatement:statement
                                                                       atColumn:1];
        int configId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);
        NSString* configIdNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",configId];

        NSMutableArray* specItems = [configurationsWithSpecItems objectForKey:configIdNumber];
        if(specItems == nil)
        {
            specItems = [NSMutableArray new];
            [configurationsWithSpecItems setObject:specItems
                                            forKey:configIdNumber];
        }

        SpecificationItem* specItem = [SpecificationItem specificationItemWithId:specItemId
                                                                            name:specItemName];

        [specItems addObject:specItem];
        // When we read last row data, getting from here to POINT 2 takes 1s
    }
    // POINT 2
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
[self databaseClose];
return configurationsWithSpecItems;
}
```

Single read of one row takes 2-3ms, but after last one getting out of while loop takes 1s, which is too much for me.

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output for this query:

```
0 0 1 SCAN TABLE Configuration (~100000 rows) 
0 0 0 EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
1 0 0 SEARCH TABLE Configuration USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (model_id=?) (~7 rows) 
0 1 0 SEARCH TABLE SpecItem USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
```

Comment: Please show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for your query.

Comment: 0 0 1 SCAN TABLE Configuration (~100000 rows)
0 0 0 EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
1 0 0 SEARCH TABLE Configuration USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (model_id=?) (~7 rows)
0 1 0 SEARCH TABLE SpecItem USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)

Comment: Please add this information to your question. And why is the table name `SpecItem` and not `Spec`?

Comment: Problem edited. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure about `ConfigurationSpec`? And where does `model_id` come from? `configurationsIdStr`? That subquery appears to be important.

Answer (score 0):

There are two explanations for the delay; one or both might apply:

- All the records that match are at the beginning of the `Configuration` table. After the last matching record, SQLite still has to search through all the remaining records, but none matches.
- SQLite creates a temporary index on the `model_id` column because it estimates that the query would be even slower without it. After the query has finished, that index must be deleted again; what you see is the time needed to synchronize at the end of the (automatic) transaction.

Create an index on the `model_id` column will help avoiding both of these points.

If possible, you should try to merge the subquery (in `configurationsIdStr`) into the outer query; instead of:

```sql
... ConfigurationSpec.configuration_id IN (
           SELECT configuration_id FROM Configuration WHERE model_id = 42)
```

use something like this:

```sql
... ConfigurationSpec.model_id = 42
```

Avoiding that indirection makes it much easier for SQLite to optimize the query execution.